# RewriteRule ^.*$ index.php [NC,L]

Tags: apache, .htaccess

I'm trying to redirect non-existent webpages to my index.php.

I've created a .htaccess file in the same folder as my index.php with this data.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -s [OR] 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -l [OR]
Rewritecond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d

RewriteRule ^.*$ - [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^.*$ index.php [NC,L]
```

I'm using Wampserver and the httpd.conf for the apache server is set to

> AllowOverride All

But still when I try to enter a non existent webpage I get the 404 error.
Any idea?

EDIT.
By the way, I've seen this post [HERE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2439562/apache-rewriterule-index-php-nc-l-not-working) And tried the stuff held there, but it didn't work for me.

Answer (score 4):

Why don't you just use the ErrorDocument directive?

```
ErrorDocument 404 index.php
```

It's a lot simpler, and has a lot less overhead.

If you insist on using mod_rewrite, you may use De Morgan's law, and don't care about the case when the page does exist: it will be served normally anyway, you don't need to do the explicit RewriteRule ^.*$.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-s
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-l
Rewritecond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^.*$ index.php [NC,L]
```

That said, I think the snippet you posted should work. I'm not familiar with Wampserver at all, but it seems you have to explicitly [enable the mod_rewrite module](http://www.shariff.org/how-to-enable-htaccess-in-wamp-server.html), have you done that?

Also, redirecting nonexistent pages to the index.php, without indicating to robots or users that the page doesn't exist, isn't a very good idea. A pretty error page with links to valid pages would be a lot better choice.